# CSS vertical alignment issue in IE9

Tags: html, css

I have a button with text (I am using Cuffon for the text) which must be vertically and horizontally centered. However, text-align is working but vertical align is not working.

Here is my div block:

```
btndownload
{
    background-color: #512c1d;
    background: url('../Images/Btn_Brwn.png');
    background-size: 103px 32px;
    color: #B6BD00;
    width: 103px;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: 0 solid #512c1d;
    margin-top: 6px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-shadow: none;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-right: -16px;
    line-height:25px;
}

<div id="btnDownload" title="Download Image" class="btndownload">
    <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="DOWNLOAD" style="width: 72px; height: 13px;">
    <canvas width="77" height="13" style="width: 77px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"> 
    </canvas><cufontext>DOWNLOAD</cufontext></cufon>
```

Now button with the "Download" text is vertically centered with Chrome, IE10 and above, and Firefox, but not IE9.

Possible mistakes can be `font-size :13 px` but `line-height:25px`
there is `padding-top:10px`; but it is also vertically centered.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work

```
#btnDownload {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -150px; /* Negative half of width. */
        margin-top: -100px; /* Negative half of height. */
}
```

along with the rest of your css ofcourse.

*Not tested in IE but worked accurately in both chrome and firefox.

Comment: Might work on Chrome, but the OP is asking specifically about IE9.